# How to make the text fit a google marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have written a code for displaying markers on the screen. And I have a text within the marker. The text is a 5 digit number which doesnot fit the marker. How can make the number to be within the marker?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Google Map API V3: Add Marker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 20; padding: 20 }
#map_canvas{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 740px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.576897,-122.419184),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var locations = [

[47.648197,-122.282784,11500,"0"]

    ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        var shape = {
      coord: [10, 10, 10, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 10],
      type: 'poly'
  };


        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 

          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
          pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+locations[i][2]+'|808000|0000FF',
    null, 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(140, 210),
    new google.maps.Size(40, 60)
    );       
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon:pinIcon,
            shape:shape,
            title: locations[i][3]



        });
        }


      }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print "11500" (locations[i][2]) inside my marker but when trying to do so it goes outside the marker.

Comment: Please provide code and context. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have put in the code , can you now please help me?

Comment: Its a little urgent , any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is simply that you're using the wrong icon from the charts api. The pin type is of course not going to meet your needs for displaying the text; and you can't scale it after requesting it (as you seem to be trying in your code) since you'll be scaling the icon along with the text.

So two things to change:

1. MarkerIcon is deprecated, luckily it's easy to switch to Icon.
2. Use a different marker type that's designed for displaying text. [Bubbles](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#bubbles), probably.

Here is the relevant chunk of code that I just tested:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
var pinIcon = {
    url: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|'+locations[i][2]+'|C6EF8C|000000'
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: pinIcon,
    title: locations[i][3]
});
```

I removed the `shape` attribute, because it's no longer valid with the new icon anyway. There is some image shifting during zoom, you can play with the attributes to fix that if you wish. And finally, there's different styles at that link to customize with.

Note: If this is to be used for a long time, know that the charts api is also deprecated, I think it's up until 2015.